# Intellij Click to see difference link

Tags: python, intellij-idea, python-unittest

How can one make `Click to see difference` link in output console. There is suggestions that if you will print it in [some template](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/3f7e93e20b7e79ba389adf593b3b59e46a3e01d1/plugins/testng/src/com/theoryinpractice/testng/model/TestProxy.java#L50) then link will appear. But it doesn't work. For, example I try in Python:

```
print(" expected:<abc> but was:<cde>")
```

and expect:

[image]

as same as unittest.assertEqual do.
How can I acheve this? Thank you!

Comment: It works only for test cases.It's not possible to show it for simple output.